# mysql select with node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to do a code that verifies if a player is already registered in a tournament and I have his Discord Tag and the Tournament ID. The thing is, the
query I made does not brings results. Thank you.

```
function verifyPlayerNotRegistered(tournamentID, discordTag){
    var verifyPlayerNotRegisteredSQL = "SELECT * 
                                        FROM players 
                                        WHERE tournamentID = (?) 
                                        and discordTag  = (?)"
    var playerData = [discordTag, tournamentID];
    con.query(verifyPlayerNotRegisteredSQL, playerData, function(err, results){
        if(err) throw err;
        if (results.length > 0){
            console.log("Ya está registrado en este torneo");
            return message.reply(`${discordTag} ya está registrado en ese torneo`);
        }else{
            return generatePlayerID(tournamentID, discordTag);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: here you don't need all columns so only return 1

Comment: You don't need `= (?)` you can and should just do `=?`.

Comment: The `()` are not required round the `(?)`, but I am not sure that it would break the query as I have never written a query like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're calling `return` inside a callback function but the surrounding function does not have a callback handler, so you just return results into the void, throwing them away. Unless you have a method for properly accepting these results they won't go anywhere.

You need to rewrite to accept a callback:

```
function verifyPlayerNotRegistered(tournamentID, discordTag, cb) {
    var verifyPlayerNotRegisteredSQL = "SELECT * 
                                        FROM players 
                                        WHERE tournamentID = (?) 
                                        and discordTag  = (?)"
    var playerData = [discordTag, tournamentID];
    con.query(verifyPlayerNotRegisteredSQL, playerData, function(err, results){
        if(err) cb(err);
        if (results.length > 0){
            console.log("Ya está registrado en este torneo");
            cb(null, message.reply(`${discordTag} ya está registrado en ese torneo`));
        }else{
            cb(null, generatePlayerID(tournamentID, discordTag));
        }
    });
}
```

Note that this function, being async, *must* be called with a callback function.

Consider using `await` and a Promise-compatible library like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org). Doing this with callbacks is making a mess of things. You can then `return` values without having to do the callback dance.

An async version looks a lot cleaner:

```
async function verifyPlayerNotRegistered(tournamentID, discordTag) {
  let verifyPlayerNotRegisteredSQL = "SELECT * 
                                      FROM players 
                                      WHERE tournamentID = (?) 
                                      and discordTag  = (?)"
  let playerData = [discordTag, tournamentID];

  let results = await con.query(verifyPlayerNotRegisteredSQL, playerData);

  if (results.length > 0){
    console.log("Ya está registrado en este torneo");
    return message.reply(`${discordTag} ya está registrado en ese torneo`);
  }

  return generatePlayerID(tournamentID, discordTag);
}
```

Also given that it's 2020 and not 2010 you should be using `let` and `const` in preference to `var` whenever possible. This helps keep your variables correctly scoped.